# How to ensure user has really made facebook login?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a PHP Web application, and I`m trying to implement Facebook login. I've designed the process like this:

1. The user clicks the FB Login button.
2. A request is sent to facebook to initiate login process (AJAX).
3. A Javascript callback function in my code is called to inform the user has completed the login.
4. My js code calls Facebook API to obtain users detail (Like name and email).
5. My JS Code sends the obtained data to my server code (PHP), wich will store the user email in Session to keep the user authenticated.

My fear is that would be easy for someone to fake a request in step 5 and send the user email and name to the PHP application.

So my question is: How can the PHP Server code ensure the facebook login was made, and the email sent is the same used to login?

Comment: for step 2: I don't think there's a way for that, the facebook will just give you a form or forcely redirect you to a login page which you will going filled  or continue button, I haven't seen yet a method which you just send a login credentials and returns if its success

Comment: Using the token that you will get back after Step 2, you should then be able to call `https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=[token]`. The returned object will contain `email` which can be used to verify against what you received from FB client-side. Effectively, you are validating the token server side as security measure.

Comment: Don't request data client-side and then send it to the server. Send the access token _only_ to the server, and then make API requests using it from there. // https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security

Comment: Ben Snaize and CBroe, that seems to be the right way. I'll try that

Answer (score 0):

*The session variables are stored on the PHP server, on the users device only one cookie will be stored containing a session id, so the PHP server knows which session the user belongs to.
It would't be easy to fake the session id, because it is generated randomly and it would be hard to bruteforce it.*

**Note:** If something (what I wrote) is wrong, please correct me in the comments

**Source**: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

**EDIT:** The PHP server should get the data he wanted and the confirmation that the user successfully logged in (if the user actually did that)